# What's correct way of writing following sentence: I'm reading them (documents) as they being posted

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, being

*I am reading them as they are being posted.*

---

What is correct way of using verb ***(BE)*** in writing above sentence?
What is the difference between using ***these/those*** (documents), and should the noun (these **document**) be used instead of pronoun (**them**). Is the pronoun ***them*** (for documents) admissible in that place in a sentence, if another (**they**, again for same documents) is used immediately afterward.

- I'm reading (them) (these/those documents) **as (they) are being** posted.
  ...OR...
- I'm reading (them) (these/those documents) **as (they) being** posted.
  ...OR...
- I'm reading (them) (these/those documents) **as (they) have being** posted.
  ...OR...
- I'm reading (them) (these/those documents) **as (they) have been** posted.
  ...OR...
- Non of the above.

---

He has run the company for five years now.

Is the verb has run correct here? If "he" is still in post, the action is still in progress, so should the verb be a continuous/progressive verb like He has been running? Does the inclusion of "now" make a difference here?

Comment: Why complicate matters? Two continuous forms in one utterance is unnecessary - *I'm reading them as they **are** posted* (or in speech, *as **they're** posted* ) is easier to write, read, say, and hear. (i.e. - ***none of the above**!* :)

Comment: It's sometimes hard to differentiate between common and official slang, especially for non-native speaker - I assumed that I could use "I'm reading them as they are posted", but I wasn't sure is it appropriate for official usage
Thanks anyway, it's good to confirm since I wasn't sure

Comment: There's no such thing as "official" usage for English. There's "formal", which would exclude our contractions **they're, I'm**. But as a general principle, native speakers (particularly, *eloquent and articulate* native speakers) tend to use the simplest acceptable tense form for the context unless there's a good reason not to. If you want to understand this better (particularly, the *exceptions* to that principle), you'd probably get more appropriate answers asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Of course, I should have said "formal" for the purpose of "official" (correspondence).
Thanks for the suggestion, though, appreciate it.

Comment: Bear in mind "formal" has nothing to do with the usage you're asking about (i.e. - there's nothing "informal" about using a simpler tense here). Also note that if there *had* been any difference, the fact that your example is definitely *informal* (because of the contracted ***I'm***) could well have led to you being given inappropriate information.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice about tense ( in this context, I mean)
Also I rarely used this particular contraction "I am to I'm" - habit I suppose
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am reading them as they are posted.**

Because "documents" is plural, you need to use "them" and "they". Because the sentence is in the present tense, you must use "are", which is the present tense form of the verb "to be". This may seem confusing, since "being" is also a form of "to be", but it is the progressive tense form, which is used to highlight the ongoing (*progressing*) nature of an action.

[Source](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

### I'm reading them (documents) as they are being posted.

Comment: first interaction :-) this works fine.
thanks to dockeryZ, really, thanks friend !

Comment: it sounds better though if you say, **those documents** or **these documents**

Comment: you mean "im reading those docs as they are being posted" ?

Comment: it depends where the documents are in relation to you.  *These* means they are close to you, *Those* mean they are away from you.

Comment: i suppose "those" then, as they are online somewhere - this will do ... for now .... thank you friend, very much

Comment: done !
sorry, i did it after the firs reply, but obviously not correctly, now it's green :-)

Comment: Up arrows are fun to push too. :P

Comment: yeah, i did that too, but I'm not sure if it registered since i don't have enough points to see it myself ;-))